# jQuery immediately invoked function in CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

On the jQuery page [explaining how to make plugins](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), there's this bit of code:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  var shade = "#556b2f";

  $.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", shade );
    return this;
  };
}( jQuery ));
```

How do I represent this in CoffeeScript? If I try this:

```
do ($) ->
  x = 'do nothing'
```

It compiles as:

```
(function($) {
  var x;
  return x = 'do nothing';
})($);
```

I can't figure out how to pass the `jQuery` object to the function.

Comment: Does this help? - http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/plugin

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Does it protect the $ alias?

Comment: Just as an aside, you could simply have done `do (jQuery) -> $ = jQuery; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way in CoffeeScript that you'd do it in JavaScript. You just need to toss in some extra parentheses:

```
(($) ->
  # plugin goes here and uses $
)(jQuery)
```

That becomes this JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

If you have a pathological fear of parentheses then you can still use `do` but you'd set up the `$` alias using a default value:

```
do ($ = jQuery) ->
  # plugin code goes here
```

That is also translated to:

```
(function($) {
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: heh. pathological fear. great description.